# Whether a AR(P) process is stationary or not?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, arma, stationarity

In practice, how to evaluate whether a AR(P) process is stationary or not?

How to determine the order for the AR and MA model?

Comment: For an AR process to be stationary the roots of the AR polynomial must be outside the unit circle. Thus if the model is an AR(1) the coefficient must be absolutely less than 1.0 . All AR processes are not stationary.

Comment: @IrishStat - yes, you're correct. I wasn't thinking straight. Perhaps you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @IrishStat: I do not understand your comment, particularly the last sentence. Is there a typo there?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "AR processes are not necessarily stationary"

Comment: @IrishStat: Ah. That makes more sense. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extract the roots of the polynomial. If all the roots are outside the unit circle then the process is stationary. Model identification aids can be found on the web. Fundamentally the pattern of the ACF's and the pattern of the PACF's are used to identify which model might be a good starting model. If there are more significant ACF's than significant PACF's then an AR model is suggested as the ACF is dominant. if the converse is true where the PACF is dominant then an  MA model might be appropriate. The order of the model is suggested by the number of significant values in the subordinate.

Comment: Actualy the roots should not be on the unit circle. If the roots are inside the unit circle, the solution is stationary, but not invertible.

Comment: Where can I find the proof of such theorem (or at least an schema of the proof ?)

Comment: Where can I find more info on acf vs pacf for AR vs MA model?

Comment: https://autobox.com/pdfs/ForecastingSeminar.pdf starting at slide 161 would be a good practical place to start..

Comment: https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm might also be  useful IF AND ONLY IF your data is free of pulses , level/step shifts, seasonal pulses and/or local time trends AND has parameters that don't change over time AND has an error variance that doesn't change over time. Simple model identification tools work when the data is simple and uncomplicated. Otherwise  Not So Much. !

Answer (score 20):

If you have an `AR(p)` process like this:

$$
y_t = c + \alpha_1 y_{t - 1} + \cdots + \alpha_p y_{t - p}
$$

Then you can build an equation like this:

$$
z^p - \alpha_1 z^{p - 1} - \cdots - \alpha_{p - 1} z - \alpha_p = 0
$$

Find the roots of this equation, and if *all* of them are less than 1 in absolute value, then the process is stationary.

Comment: It's nice to see you contributing answers.  Thanks!

Comment: Note, that you wrote _less_ while it has to be _greater_ ("outside the unit circle").

Comment: @DmitrijCelov: No, I don't think so. Look carefully. It appears robbrit has used the $z$-transform and then multiplied by an additional $z^p$ factor, which will not change the location of the roots, except for adding one (of multiplicity $p$) at zero. If you factor out a $z^p$ and then substitute $B = z^{-1}$, you'll arrive at something that may look more familiar to you. The roots of the polynomial in $B$ must lie outside the unit circle. But, there is a simple correspondence between the roots of the polynomial in $B$ and the associated one in $z$. Cheers. :)

Comment: @cardinal, you  are right. robbrit, is not mentioning the $z$ transform, though yes he has made the one. The most of statistical packages however will return the roots for $1- \alpha_1 z - \dots -\alpha_p z^p = 0$ not for this one, so it could be a missleading suggestion for not so careful users (like me :D) if the $B= z^{-1}$ is not stressed. Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @DmitrijCelov: It gave me a moment's pause on first reading as well. When I said "look carefully", it was not intended in any way as an *admonishment* (though I can see how it could be read that way!), but rather only as a sign that there was something subtle to be aware of. Cheers. :)

Comment: Actually I grabbed the equation from Wikipedia, which is consistent with the stationarity condition from when I took a time series course back in university. I guess different people approach this problem differently!

Comment: @robbrit: You actually need (just) a little bit more than the conditions you've stated to guarantee a (causal) stationary $\mathrm{AR}(p)$ process. Also, as mpiktas alludes to in his remarks to IrishStat's answer, it is possible to have an $\mathrm{AR}(p)$ process where all the roots of your equation are actually outside the unit circle.