# Is there a fast algorithm to check for AR(p) stationarity?

Tags: time-series, polynomial

It is well-known that an AR(p) process 
$$
x_t=\sum_{i=1}^p \varrho_i x_{t-i} + \epsilon_t \,,
$$
is causal and stationary if and only if the roots of the polynomial
$$
\mathcal{P}(u) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^p \varrho_i u^i
$$
are all outside the unit circle in the complex plane. (Here is a [Cross Validated discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/19788/7224) on the topic.)

My question is whether or not there exists a faster algorithm than the naïve one that consists in (a) finding the roots of $\mathcal{P}$ and (b) checking none one them is inside the unit circle.

Comment: This is a mathematical question.

Comment: @vinux: It is more of a computational question in that I am looking for the smallest power $d$ such that the answer can be produced in a time $\text{O}(p^d)$...

Comment: The process, as it's written is always causal. The condition about the roots tells if the system is stable - which implies stationarity. But it's more common to speak about stability conditions, rather than stationarity conditions, IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Schur-Cohn](http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~randy/publications/RLM_journal/J11.pdf) algorithm has $d=2$; this is what I learned in a computational statistics class at Berkeley some years ago.

Comment: For comparison purposes, do you also know of the order of an efficient root finder?

Comment: I think they are also $d=2$, using the following thought process.  Evaluation of a p-degree polynomial is $O(p)$.  Finding a single root should be independent of the order of the polynomial.  After the root is found, the polynomial can be reduced to a polynomial of degree $p-1$, but this doesn't affect the order.  So each of the $p$ roots takes $O(p)$ to find, leading to an $O(p^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins-Traub, which is what is used in IMSL, is $O(p^2)$: http://www.jstor.org/pss/2949376.

Comment: Superb! I though it would be more in $\text{O}(p^3)$ because of the same thought process with a $\text{O}(p^2)$ computing cost on the polynomial itself.

Comment: Horner's method (http://cnx.org/content/m15099/latest/) allows linear computing cost of the polynomial and is much more stable than evaluating it as it's written.  I'm sure there are lots of others!

Answer (score 5):

It is unnecessary to find the $p$ complex roots as far as
these are not to be used for themselves. Moreover, most (if not all)
root finding processes can fail for large $p$.

Another solution is as follows.
The $\mathrm{AR}(p)$ model can be reparametrised thanks to its $p$
partial autocorrelations (PACs) $\zeta_k$ for $1 \le k \le p$.  The PACs are often denoted as $\phi_{k,k}$ because their
computation involves an array $\phi_{k,\ell}$. There is a one-to-one
correspondence between the vector $\boldsymbol{\rho}$ of the $p$
coefficients in the stationarity region and the vector
$\boldsymbol{\zeta}$ in the region defined by the $p$ conditions
$|\zeta_k | < 1$ for $1 \le k \le p$.  The transformation "AR to
PAC" $\boldsymbol{\rho} \mapsto \boldsymbol{\zeta}$ is quite simple
and is given as a pretty recursion formula due to Barndorff-Nielsen
and Schou. Testing stationarity from the vector of coefficients boils
down to computing the $\zeta_k$ and stop as soon as one condition $|
\zeta_k | \ge 1$ is found.
The less well-known inverse transform "PAC to AR"
$\boldsymbol{\zeta} \mapsto \boldsymbol{\rho}$ is available explicitly
(due to Monahan), and is as simple as is the direct one. It might also
be useful in some cases.

The two transformations are implemented (in R) in a CRAN R package named
**FitAR** which provides as well an efficient
`invertibleQ` function to test stationarity. The package is
described in the following article where list of references is
provided.

McLeod, A.I. and Zhang Y., "Improved Subset Autoregression: With R Package"
*Journal of Statistical Software*, vol. 28, Issue 2, Oct 2008.
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i02

Comment: Further: PARCOR coefficients are the same (except for a sign change) as the "reflection coefficients", which can be obtained from the AR coefficients via Levinson-Durbin recursion. And, essentially, testing for reflection coefficients having modulus less than one, is the same as the Schur-Cohn test in the other answer.
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470611104.app6/pdf