# Automatic process to determine stationarity of AR(p) model

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

I have read that an *AR(p)* process is stationary if all of the roots of it's characteristic equation are greater than one in absolute value.

Does this mean that I can find out if my data set is stationary by the following two methods:

A) Fit the data to *AR(1)*, *AR(2)*, ... , *AR(n)* processes with regression, approximate the roots of the characteristic equations of these processes, and check if the absolute value of roots are greater than one.

B) Fit the data to *AR(1)*, *AR(2)*, ... , *AR(n)* processes, and check if the error terms are white noise.

This is assuming the data is fit well by an *AR* process, but that I do not know the correct value of *p*.

I could also difference the data and repeat the process if the above fails.

Also, would it make any sense to fit the partial correlations to a sine wave or exponential to help determine if the data is an *AR(p)* process?

Comment: Fit model (flexible) to data (fixed), not data to a model.

Comment: [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20870/10479) can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @RichardHardy